# How do I avoid li element going down when I open another li element

Tags: html, css

So I have this list with some elements in it. The problem is that, when I open one of the li elements in my browser, the other li elements go down too. This is a photo for you to understand it

[image]

HTML:

```
<ul class="gadgets-list">
<li class="gadget"><img src="iconmonstr-keyboard-2-240.png" class="image">Keyboards<span class="caret"></span></a>
<p class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</li>
<li class="gadget"><img class="image" src="iconmonstr-mouse-8-240.png">Mouses<span class="caret"></span></a></li>
<li class="gadget"><img  class="image" src="iconmonstr-headphones-1-240.png">Headsets<span class="caret"></span></a></li>
<li class="gadget"><img class="image" src="iconmonstr-computer-1-240.png">Monitors<span class="caret"></span></a></li>
<li class="gadge"><img class="image" src="iconmonstr-cpu-1-240.png">Other components<span class="caret"></span></a></li>
```

CSS:

```
.gadgets-list {
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  word-spacing: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.item {
  word-spacing: normal;
}
.gadge {
  list-style: none;
  word-spacing: normal;
  display: inline-block;
}
p {
  width: 450px
}
```

Comment: Try to change it to display: block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to your `gadget` as the `li`s are inline-block elements, and it all works fine I guess.

Please let me know your feedback. Thanks!

PS: typo for the gadget too... :)

```css
.gadgets-list {
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  word-spacing: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.item {
  word-spacing: normal;
}
.gadget {
  list-style: none;
  word-spacing: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
p {
  width: 450px
}
```

```html
<ul class="gadgets-list">
  <li class="gadget">
    <img src="iconmonstr-keyboard-2-240.png" class="image">Keyboards<span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <p class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </li>
  <li class="gadget">
    <img class="image" src="iconmonstr-mouse-8-240.png">Mouses<span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="gadget">
    <img class="image" src="iconmonstr-headphones-1-240.png">Headsets<span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="gadget">
    <img class="image" src="iconmonstr-computer-1-240.png">Monitors<span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="gadget">
    <img class="image" src="iconmonstr-cpu-1-240.png">Other components<span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is typo in your css its `.gadget` not `.gadge`

[View this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/bozixe/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: yes but its also a list item so class name should be  `.gadget` and make your `.item { display: table }`